# Eth Miner: Buy or Build?

Tags: rig

I've been researching this for about a month now (motherboards, GPU, PSU, racks, Watts etc) and ready to pull the plug on the Very Late just-getting-into-it.

I'm simply thinking about a single 6 GPU miner.

Of course, there are people on Amazon and Craigslist, etc selling the complete rigs (Talking ETH here, not ASIC)
From what I can tell, these builders are taking a measly $200-$300 profit.
Anyways, those units somewhat tempt me, as I'm having a hard time finding the hardware required in a short window of time.

Thoughts on 'aftermarket' sales of built rigs?

--edit--
Specifically thinking of security.  Has there been any historical scams with pre-built miners?

Comment: it is much better to invest in emerging cryptos. if you know how to find the good ones, your investment will be much lower, you are going to have much more free time and you are going to make much more money than in mining.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-built miners will already be nearing end-of-life, and end-of-profitability. Basically, any smart miner will use up most the profits on a mining rig, and then sell it right before it is useless, in order to scrape the maximum amount of cash from a miner. (So don't be the sucker who buys this miner from them).

You are way too late to the mining party, unless you are strictly doing it as a hobby/learning experience, then go right ahead! Just know that you will probably lose money/barely break even. You will also invest a large amount of time into your miner to make sure it runs correctly.

Comment: thanks, apparently it's only 3 months old and the guy that's selling it is giving up on mining to do exactly what you suggest. (just buying the whatever he was mining)
And yes, it's a hobby/learning experience, I don't expect to re-experience what I missed out on with a 2012 bitcoin miner.

Comment: @Octoth0rpe sounds like you should go ahead and buy it then. Good luck mining!